# To prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^n}=1?$
I have noticed that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}}}=1/e$, so the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$converges in $[-\frac1e,\frac1e]$, then I suppose to find the sum-function of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$. However, this is surely difficult for me. Could anyone help me out? Sincerely thanks for your help.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: @MartinSleziakOK, I see, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can write the second sum in terms of the Lambert W function (see, in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions): $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} x^n=-W(-x)$$

Comment: The first identity at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities: $W(xe^x)=x$ should also be useful.

Comment: Well done!  Gotta love the $W$!

Answer (score 5):

The function 
$$W(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} n^{n-1} z^n}{n!}$$
is called the [Lambert $W$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) ([see also Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)), so you are trying to compute $-W(-e^{-1})$. As Wikipedia says, $W(-e^{-1}) =-1$ so your claimed identity is right. More generally,
$$z = W(z) e^{W(z)}$$
so 
$$-e^{-1} = W(-e^{-1}) e^{W(-e^{-1})},$$
which strongly suggests the correct result $W(-e^{-1}) =-1$.

This is already mostly said in par's answer. I write further because your language suggests that you think that a power series with ratio $r$ necessarily converges on the closed interval $[-r,r]$. In fact, you don't know whether or not there is convergence at the end points. There is in this case, but it isn't obvious.

Comment: I did it again, actually, I am wrong.Sincerely thanks.